# python. Получить значение поля Телефон

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Берем анкету https://vedushi.ru/vedushi/tretyakov-roman/
Задача - получить номер телефона.

1. Пробовал selenium + python

   ```
    def get_phone():
        link = 'https://vedushi.ru/vedushi/tretyakov-roman/'
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.headless = False
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

        driver.get(link)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,500)", "")

        button = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'div.big.dark.phone')
        button.click()
        time.sleep(1)

        phone = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.big.dark.phone').text
        print(phone)

        time.sleep(5)
        driver.quit()
   ```

Итог: после клика на кнопку, действия типа driver.page_source > сохранить код страницы в файл, показывает, что структура страницы, где блок с телефоном

```
<div class="big dark phone">
    <a>+7 926 ***-**-**
         <span class="show_phone">Показать телефон</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

осталась не изменная, но если смотреть через открытый автобраузер > inspect > ... в коде появляются еще пару тегов А, которые не получается найти.....

2. Пытался requestom сделать, но и тут попал в просак, в силу неопытность)

   ```
    headers = {'user-agent': FAKE_USER.random}
    payload = {'artist_id': 1}
    r = requests.post("https://vedushi.ru/inc/ajax/contacts_click.php", headers=headers, params=payload)
    print(r.json())
   ```

Очень прошу помочь и хотяб минимально обьяснить где я косячу и как правильно!
Всем откликнувшимся Огромная благодарность заранее!

Answer (score 1):

Ваша ошибка при работе с requests в том, что вам нужно явно указать, что вы в post запросе передаете json. Тогда requests изменит заголовок Content-Type на application/json.

```
import requests
payload = {'artist_id': 1}
r = requests.post("https://vedushi.ru/inc/ajax/contacts_click.php", json=payload)
print(r.json())
```

Ответ тоже прилетает в json:

```
{'result': 'success', 'phone': '<a href="tel:+79266662244">+7 926 666-22-44</a>'}
```

Если вам нужно получить id артиста, то он хранится тут:

```
<input name="artist_id" value="2119" type="hidden">
```

Answer (score 1):

Пункт 2 - почти правильно сделали. Только payload надо было передать как json.

```
import requests

payload = {"artist_id": 1}
r = requests.post("https://vedushi.ru/inc/ajax/contacts_click.php", json=payload)
print(r.json())
```

Результат:

```
{'result': 'success', 
 'phone': '<a href="tel:+79266662244">+7 926 666-22-44</a>'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так. Выдает только номер.

```
url = "https://vedushi.ru/vedushi/tretyakov-roman/"
r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, timeout=10))

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

phone = soup.find('div', class_="big dark phone")
phone.span.decompose()
current_phone = phone.get_text(strip=True)
        
print(current_phone)
```